# How to access this array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like the code to be able to access the string "carros", in the following array:

```
var ourArray = [["carros", 4], 5, "casa"];
```

Comment: Please ask in english.

Comment: Not sure who like this question, I tried translate from spanish to english :)

Answer (score 3):

You'd get the first element with index `0`, then the first element of that array with index `0`:

```js
var ourArray = [["carros", 4], 5, "casa"];
console.log(ourArray[0][0]);
```